# Delete objects with checkboxes

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want to delete objects in a list which are marked with checkboxes. I have read through other post and tried to understand it, but I seem to be missing something.

views.py

```
def phase1(request, id):
  ...
  if request.POST.get('delete'):
    Descriptor.objects.filter(id__in=request.POST.getlist('item')).delete()
    return render(request, 'szenario/phase1.html', context)
```

template phase1.html

```
<ul>
  {% for Descriptor in projectdescriptors %}
        <li>
          <tr class="item">
            <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="{{Descriptor.name}}">
          </tr>
          {{Descriptor.name}}
        </li>
  {% endfor %}

  <form  method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete selected descriptors" /></h1>
  </form>
</ul
```

Pressing the button reloads the page, but the selected entries are still there. What am i doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Note: I aim on using AJAX and signals as soon as i understand how to use them, but for now i just wanted to make a simple solution to focus on other tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form  method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
<ul>
  {% for Descriptor in projectdescriptors %}
        <li>
          <tr class="item">
            <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="{{Descriptor.id}}">
          </tr>
          {{Descriptor.name}}
        </li>
  {% endfor %}


    <h1><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete selected descriptors" /></h1>
  </form>
</ul>
```

your items should be inside the `form tag`

Comment: Thanks. For later visitors: I also had to change `value="{{Descriptor.name}}"` to `value="{{Descriptor.id}}"` because `id__in=request.POST.getlist('item')` obviously needs the id.